# COM Interop error, class not registered when using MSMQ Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, interop, msmq

I've referenced the MSMQ v3 Object Library in a VS2010 C# project only to get:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0188401C-247A-4FED-99C6-BF14119D7055} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I've registered the library the reference points to:

> regsvr32 C:\windows\system32\mqoa.dll

What am I missing?
Assuming this works, what will I have to do at deployment to ensure the app will run on other machines with MSMQ installed?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Programs and features in Windows. Open MSMQ node and install MSMQ Triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a 64-bits windows? Are you compiling in x86 (default for VS2010)?

Consider registering mqoa from c:\windows\syswow64 (with regsvr32 from there too) instead.

Comment: Both machines tested are 32-bit XP machines and I changed the target platform of the calling library to x86 with no change.